# Mysql ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP vs. trigger that sets time to now() after update

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

While searching for something else, I found this trigger in our test database:

```sql
begin
     set NEW.UpdatedAt = now();
end
```

I'm puzzled... Is this any different from changing the column definition to the following?

```sql
alter table TableName change UpdatedAt ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Are any advantages that I'm not seing to doing it in a trigger?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the table structure. Older versions of MySQL (prior to 5.6 I think) could not support both a current timestamp for a row insert and a separate column to update timestamp for last modification. This could have been a workaround.  I'd personally much rather see it in an `ON UPDATE` attribute than a trigger that's mostly invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For earlier versions of MySQL, the `ON UPDATE` was available only for columns of datatype `TIMESTAMP`.  That functionality was not supported for `DATETIME` or any other datatypes.

And with `TIMESTAMP` columns, it could be kind of tricky to get table defined with two `TIMESTAMP` columns to be automatically set; to get `NOW()` assigned to one column when the row was inserted, and to get `NOW()` assigned to a different column when the row was updated.

Triggers can work around those limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! One follow up question: how old are we talking about? I think we've been running 5.6 for quite some time. From what I read, the problem is older than that... Maybe an old habit from the devs.

Comment: I know that MySQL 5.1 did not support the automatic update for DATETIME datatype, only TIMESTAMP. (I'm not sure about 5.5) This automatic update of TIMESTAMP (and now DATETIME) columns is a MySQL specific feature, and isn't available in Oracle, SQL Server, ... so another possible rationale for the triggers is that the developer was familiar with that pattern from other DBMS, or the database design was ported from another DBMS.